# 401 error accessing web service

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to consume a web service from SharePoint Foundation 2010 using asp.net.

I am getting a 401 unauthorised error.

I know this means missing or invalid credentials but I can't seem to find out why.

I can access the web service page from a standard browser without authentication, that is no challenge for user/password. This works both from the server itself as well as from a remote client browser.

Here is the code:

```
    Dim wsLists As New JEMS30LISTS.Lists
    Dim dtTasks As New DataTable
    Dim xmlDoc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
    Dim ndQuery, ndViewFields, ndQueryOptions, ndListItems As System.Xml.XmlNode
    Dim szListName, szListsUrl, szUsername, szPassword, szDomain As String
    szListsUrl = "https://demo.********.com/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx"
    szUsername = "*********"
    szPassword = "************"
    szDomain = "***********"


    ndQuery = xmlDoc.CreateNode(System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "")
    ndViewFields = xmlDoc.CreateNode(System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", "")
    ndQueryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateNode(System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, "QueryOptions", "")
    ndQueryOptions.InnerXml = "<IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>" _
                            + "<DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>"
    If bAllFields = True Then
        ndViewFields.InnerXml = ""
    Else
        ndViewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name=""TEAS_x0020_5_x0020_Task_x0020_Nu"" /> <FieldRef Name=""TEAS_x0020_5_x0020_SubTask"" /> <FieldRef Name=""TEAS_x0020_6_x0020_Task_x0020_Nu"" /> <FieldRef Name=""TEAS_x0020_6_x0020_Task_x0020_Nu0"" /> <FieldRef Name=""Shreds_x0020_Converted"" /> <FieldRef Name=""TEAS_x0020_6_x0020_Shred_x0020_P"" /> <FieldRef Name=""ProcessTask"" /> <FieldRef Name=""TEAS6Dept"" /> "
    End If

    ndQuery.InnerXml = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=""TEAS_x0020_5_x0020_Task_x0020_Nu"" Ascending=""True""></FieldRef></OrderBy>"
    szListName = "CORs"

    Try
        Dim cache As New System.Net.CredentialCache
        wsLists.Url = szListsUrl
        Dim vUri As New Uri(wsLists.Url)
        Dim vNW As New Net.NetworkCredential()
        cache.Add(vUri, "windows", vNW)
        wsLists.Credentials = cache
        ndListItems = wsLists.GetListItems(szListName, Nothing, ndQuery, ndViewFields, 99999, ndQueryOptions, Nothing)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write("GetListItems: " + ex.Message + "<br>")
    End Try
```

I have tried several username/password combinations as well as no authentication at all (since I am not challenged from the browser).

Can anyone give me an idea what I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Basic authorization was disabled. Not sure why that would matter because I even tried Windows authorization (which IS enabled) and that did not work either.

Turned basic authorization on and it works now.